# AWS Windows GPU instance opengl

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gpu, rdp

**Description**: I set up an AWS EC2 Windows Server 2019 instance. The instance I used is `g4dn` GPU instance class

**Purpose**: I want to use this instance for 3d modeling

**Problem**: When I open the 3d software. It says `opengl 2.0 not supported by your system`

**My failed "solutions"**:

1. Install Nvidia driver. As I initially thought it's because GPU is not present
2. Use teamviewer. Based on online tutorial. They say connecting to Windows instance via RDP, the default opengl is 1.1, and teamviewer will resolve that. However, when I connect using teamviewer and check, the opengl is still 1.1
3. I tried AWS AMI Windows server 2019 with driver installed. However, it has the same problem as the instance I manually setup

Comment: were you able to figure this out, am having same issue. Using TeamViewer is not helping. while clicking on control panel it says Current display is not using Nvidia GPU.

Comment: no solution, I gave up